# Turndown clarification: Errors in Maps JavaScript API v3.37 AND Before?

Tags: google-fusion-tables

The Google Fusion Tables Turndown message (https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417) indicates that "Maps using the Fusion Tables Layer in the Maps JavaScript API v3.37 will start to see errors in August 2019."

Does this also include versions prior to and including v3.36? Or are the v3.36 and prior safe until the Turndown on Dec. 3, 2019?

Comment: Per [versioning](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions), as of August 2019 v3.36 will be the earliest version available (and therefore the only one that wouldn't start seeing errors), and that will be turned off in November 2019.

Answer (score 0):

v3.37 and prior will support maps using the [FusionTablesLayer](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/fusiontableslayer) until the turndown of Fusion Tables on December 3, 2019. In August (this month), the weekly channel for Google Maps JavaScript API will be updated to version 3.38. 3.38 will not include the FusionTablesLayer, and maps using FusionTablesLayer with 3.38 and any future versions will not work.

More information on the [Fusion Tables turndown.](https://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/9185417)
More information on [Google Maps JavaScript API versioning.](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/versions)